# How to fix this loop for special cases in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list

So I got assigned a homework where I have to do the convexHull problem by brute force (this is to then later compare the complexity vs the normal complexHull), and I have this code:

```
def determineSideLocation(A,B,P):
#Takes point A and B and creates a vector (A ---> B), direction sensitive
d = ((P[0] - A[0])*(B[1] - A[1])) - ((P[1] - A[1])*(B[0] - A[0]))
if d < 0:
    #To the left of AB
    return -1
elif d > 0:
    #To the right of AB
    return 1
elif d == 0:
    #On AB
    return 0
```

And now I determine if all the points I want to compare are on one side or not:

```
def isAllPointsOnOneSide(vector, pointList):
    pointSideList = []

    print("vector: " + str(vector))
    print("pointList: " + str(pointList))
    for i in pointList:
        pointSideList.append(determineSideLocation(vector[0], vector[1], i))

    print("pointSideList: " + str(pointSideList))

    for j in range(0, len(pointSideList) - 1):

        if pointSideList[j] == 0:
            continue

        elif pointSideList[j+1] == 0:
            #2 options:
            #1. pointSideList[j+1] is at the end of the list (j+1 = len(pointSideList) - 1)
            #2. pointSideList[j+1] is not at the end of the list
            if j+1 == (len(pointSideList) - 1):
                continue
            else:
                if pointSideList[j+2] == 0:
                    if j+2 == (len(pointSideList) - 1):
                        continue
                    else:
                        if pointSideList[j] != pointSideList[j+3]:
                            return False
                        else:
                            continue
                elif pointSideList[j] != pointSideList[j+2]:
                    return False
                else:
                    continue
        elif pointSideList[j] != pointSideList[j+1]:
            return False
        else:
            continue
    return True
```

There is the convexHull function but its not where the problem lies. The thing is: in the `isAllPointsOnOneSide` function, it takes the list of points and makes a list of values relative to the vector, which can only be 1 (to the right), -1 (to the left) and 0 (in the vector).

I got an ankward case where the relative values were this: `[-1,0,0,0,0]` and the function breaks itself and gives a False value despite being True (all points are on the vector or on one side). I know its in the exception part, where it tries to skip comparing the current value to a 0, but I know its not ideal to keep writing more exceptions to that part.

How can I fix it to avoid the cases where the function breaks? Where it has to compare with 0 at the end of the list

Comment: Just for my understanding, should `isAllPointsOnOneSide` return True if all entries in `pointSideList` are either -1 or 0, or 1 or 0 and False otherwise? If so, couldn't you just look at `max(pointSideList) - min(pointSideList)` and return True if `<= 1` and False otherwise?

Comment: @Heike It seems that I complicated myself and I didn't think of trying that. Yes, isAllPointsOnOneSide returns true if the values are -1 and 0 or 1 and 0. That suggestion did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

@Heike gave me the answer, and it was rather simple :P

```
def isAllPointsOnOneSide(vector, pointList):
    pointSideList = []

    for i in pointList:
        pointSideList.append(determineSideLocation(vector[0], vector[1], i))

    minValue = min(pointSideList)
    maxValue = max(pointSideList)

    #If max - min is higher than 1, its a False result.
    if maxValue - minValue > 1:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

I'm sorry, and after all it was a rather simple problem, but I have been on this for several hours now (brute forcing the convexhull) and it frustated me.

Thanks to Heike again